# WPF reference to System.Runtime 4.2

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

**The Problem**
I have a WPF application which targets .NET Framework 4.7.1. I referenced a .net core 2.0 project. Now I get following error:

Error CS1705 Assembly 'DotNetCoreProject' with identity DotNetCoreProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

**What I tried**
I added a newer version (4.3) via nuget which didn't change anything. (I know, this isn't much, but I don't know what else to do...)

Comment: .NET Framework projects cannot add .NET Core projects as references.